# Android widget remoteView updates before url request is finished

Tags: android, android-widget

I have widgetProvider and GetData class.

After I click button I have to 
1. run onUpdate()

2. disable button and show progress bar
3. send url request
4. after request is done - show button and hide progress bar

In appProvider onUpdate I have code

```
rv.setInt(R.id.updateProgressBar, "setVisibility", View.VISIBLE);
rv.setInt(R.id.BtnUpdate, "setVisibility", View.GONE);

// Here I invoke method with http request from GetData class
JSONArray data = getData.get();

// Here is all correct, data comes well
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Get data: " + data.toString());

// This runs before data is ready
rv.setInt(R.id.updateProgressBar, "setVisibility", View.GONE);
rv.setInt(R.id.BtnUpdate, "setVisibility", View.VISIBLE);
```

GetData class, method get()

```
public JSONArray get() throws JSONException {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String Url = "http://url";
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Url);
        JSONArray res = null;

        try{
            httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            if(response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String json = reader.readLine();
                JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
                res = new JSONArray(tokener);
            }

        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Problem is showing button back runs immidiatelly after hiding. It doesn't wait for response.
What I do wrong? Maybe I need to use some kind of promises?

Up

Comment: Nobody knows? Really?